# Logo Proposals for Game Development

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, logo

Please post as answers below, your logo proposals for this site.

**Rules:**

- Original artwork only.
- You need to have a copy of your submission in a vector format.

*Stolen from [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming)*

Comment: I don't know if money is an issue, but you can also get logos for $250 at http://logotournament.com (and no, I don't represent them :P)

Answer (score 10):

This design is based on the currently leading URL "beyondpolygons.com," although it could also work for the "gameloop" variants.

Basically, it's a polygon, ie 3 vertices. There are several variations, some with and some without colors. In places where there is color, it's the all powerful RGB triplet. There are a few variants here where the polygon has a sharp/broken edge around it which, while also looking cool, kind of plays on the "beyond" part of the URL, ie "breaking" out of the polygon mold, etc. Also notice that the color is coming from each vertex as though they are linearly interpolated vertex colors--a play on the colored triangle we all drew when learning how to use vertices.

And yes, it is the Stack Overflow font because it looks so clean/sharp/good.

## 3: [image: Color #1]

## 2: [image: Black and White #2]

## 1: [image: Black and White #1]

There are of course a number of other combinations of color, edge style etc but hopefully the subset above gives an idea.

Edit: ordered by the preference we've been leaning towards so far (pseudo-upvoting?).

Comment: +1| Very good idea, I wonder if it would be appropriate to split this up. 1, 2 and 3 are all great. If I were to rank them though my order would be 3 > 2 > 1. 3 only ranking higher because I think a bit of color is good.

Comment: I think I'll wait a little while to split them up. If not very many designs show up, I'll split them for individual votes. If lots of designs show up I don't want to clutter everything with similar logos in separate answers.

Comment: Looks good!  I like #3 and #1

Comment: I absolutely think it needs a splash of color, and so my vote is on 3. The white in the middle looks much better in my opinion than the entire thing filled in (4).

Comment: By the way, that domain has been registered by SO, so it does appear to be our official domain not-yet-announced.

Comment: @Ricket: I'd have to agree as far as the center being filled in goes

Comment: I think #2 and #3 both look good. #2 works better as a logo, but I really like the concept of the colour in #3 - I just think the implementation could be improved. (Also: your font rendering is a bit blurry.)

Comment: @Ricket: That's not really a guarantee, they registered it very early. People with good ideas for open domains are encouraged to send the idea to SO before posting so a squatter can't grab it. That said, considering the current state of voting, I don't think the result will come as a surprise to anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Continued on [Sean James logotype](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/logo-proposals-for-game-development/133#133) since I liked the idea. It definately needs a splash of color but the original gradient between vertices is a bit uneasy to look at and will usually do badly in print. So here are some alterations on the logotype where the colors are simplified.

### 1.

Whitespace in vertices are filled with color:
[beyond polygons vertices colored http://a.imageshack.us/img706/2093/bpverticescolored.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img706/2093/bpverticescolored.png)

### 2.

Black figure around the vertices is filled with color:
[beyond polygons vertices colored http://a.imageshack.us/img269/3966/bpverticesfilledpolygon.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img269/3966/bpverticesfilledpolygon.png)

### 3.

All white space is filled with color:
[beyond polygons vertices colored http://a.imageshack.us/img36/7871/bpallwhitespacefilled.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img36/7871/bpallwhitespacefilled.png)

### 4.

As per Noctrine's comment where the white space bars between vertices are filled:

**a.**

[beyond polygons with color http://a.imageshack.us/img97/6163/bpbarsfilledccw.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img97/6163/bpbarsfilledccw.png)

**b.**

[beyond polygons with color http://a.imageshack.us/img69/3987/bpbarsfilled.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img69/3987/bpbarsfilled.png)

**c.** Tetrad's suggestion with R->G->B

[beyond polygons with color http://a.imageshack.us/img46/2015/bprgb.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img46/2015/bprgb.png)

Comment: I like number 3. It looks like people holding hands (similar to the Ubuntu logo).

Comment: @Firas: I like it for that exact reason, but I also sort of don't like it for that exact reason. Do we really need yet another logo that looks like people holding hands? It's good-looking, it's just starting to get a bit cliche.

Comment: I recommend one with color going only across one bar and filling one vertex.

Comment: Sure @Noctrine, made a quick edit.

Comment: I like the clockwise rotation in 4a, but think the order should be R -> G -> B.

Comment: @Tetrad, made a quick edit with your suggestion.

Comment: Good points. I like 4c as well.