# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design, stackexchange

Hi guys,

Thank you for your [input](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/design-for-game-development-site) on the design I proposed. The new design has launched, and let me be the first to congratulate you!

Please let me know if you see any css/styling issues on both the parent site or here on Meta. Please start a new post per bug report, and tag it with "bug" and "design" please.

Comment: This literally changed as I refereshed. It certainly was a shock. :P I don't think it deserves a thread, but is it just my computer making the text on 'Questions, Users, etc' sort of sharp rough edged? That sort of...I can't describe.

Comment: @TCD hopefully a pleasant shock :)

Comment: @The. if you can post a picture and your computer configuration it might help.

Comment: We have, the coolest Meta. Its actually different :O Just wireframes. Awesome.

Comment: It looks great, once again!

Answer (score 6):

I salute you! The design is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

New design looks great. As I posted on the question about spreading the word: it would be nice if there were a banner version of the logo so we could use it elsewhere when linking to the site, say for publicity items. Perhaps in a variety of sizes?

Comment: Thanks. Can you use http://sstatic.net/gamedev/img/apple-touch-icon.png? There are different standard banner sizes, let me know which version you need the logo for.

Comment: I was hoping to use the lovely background image (with the circular building shapes) rather than just the 3-cube icon, as it's in a blog post. Somewhere near to 400px wide would be ideal I think. Thanks.

Comment: Gentle Nudge...?