# gamedev.stackexchange: logo info

Tags: support, design, logo

the logo of gamedev.stackexchange is of interest to me. specifically does anyone know who designed it? how long ago it was made? and i am also curious how the design came about.

i ask because for some years i have had a logo design built around that concept. i am planning on using my design as a personal business logo and do not want to run into conflicts.

currently the only publicly visible iteration of my design is an iGoogle theme i made that incorporates the logo. i made and uploaded it in 2010, but i would have difficulty proving this without cooperation from Google. if you would like to see it is called "hexBird". search that on iGoogle > themes.

other than that i only have a thumbnail pencil drawing of it from 2009 and potentially a handful of friends / acquaintances who could attest to it's existence. all of my other copies (digital and hard-copy) have been lost to time.

again to re-iterate i would like to be able to use my design and would like to do so without trouble or inconvenience, to myself or others; so i would like information on the gamedev.stackexchange logo.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[New Design Launched](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/new-design-launched)

https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/166/jin

Comment: thanks for the info. and thanks to noctine for the migrate. i am new to stackexchange if you could not tell and i have always been terrible at finding things.

do you foresee any issues arising caused by the similarity of the two logo designs?

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn That's a question for lawyers. SE and You're lawyers. Please contact the SE team for further help.

Comment: Actually the first iteration of the logo can be found here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/239/design-for-game-development-site

Answer (score 2):

Our page footer:

> site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc

You should [ask them](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/help/other).