# Making sense of the “Game Development” icon

Tags: feature-request

What does the 3 blocks in the "Game Development" icon represents and how is that related to "Game Development"?

[image]

Can we change it to something that is more related to "Games" or "Development"?

Comment: Did you have something in mind that you feel would better reflect our subject matter? Or a set of criteria you'd propose to judge candidate submissions?

Comment: I guess anything related to games or "development" would be fine but I struggle to associate 3 floating cubes with games. If you want to go with "building blocks", at least make it look like building blocks. Perhaps like toys?

Comment: I'll confess a lot of my game development projects start with coloured cubes as placeholder art. [Some arguably finish that way too](https://dmgregory.itch.io/last-one-standing). Games like IDARB (It Draws a Red Box) suggest to me that this is not an uncommon development experience... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Origins & explanations of the logo and other site design tidbits can be found here: [Design for Game Development Site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/design-for-game-development-site)